# Nokogiri, How to remove unnecessary html content?

Tags: ruby, html, parsing, html-parsing, nokogiri

I have an issue with nokogiri. Let say I have this HTML

```
<html> 
<p>
        This is just an example, how to remove the next sentence using nokogiri in Ruby.
        Thank you for your help.
        <strong> XXXX </strong>
            <br/> 
            <br />
        I want to remove all the HTML after the strong XXXX
            <br />
            <br />
        <strong> YYY </strong>
</p>
```

How can I just get `"This is just an example, how to remove the next sentence using nokogiri ... Thank you for your help."`? I don't want to include the HTML from `<strong> XXXX` till rest of it.

Answer (score 2):

To exclude specifically, you may want to try

```
doc.search('//p/text()[not(preceding-sibling::strong)]').text
```

This says get all text nodes that are not after a `strong`.

Given your input, this extracts the following:

```
        This is just an example, how to remove the next sentence using nokogiri in Ruby.
        Thank you for your help.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get the text (which is what I think you are asking), then you can call the text method on the Nokogiri element. That will return you "... Thank you for your help XXX I want to remove all the HTML after the strong XXXX YYY". Here's a link to the Nokogiri [documentation](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#text-instance_method) if that's helpful - it talks about the text method. Or are you talking about trying to not get any of the text/html after the  tag?

Comment: Hi thanks for the replied. I wanna get the whole content but Exclude some of it, in the sample I made, exclude those part from "XXXX" till the rest. Since they are in  <p> I have no idea how to cut of it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you were looking for something like below:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-_HTML_
<p>
        This is just an example, how to remove the next sentence using nokogiri in Ruby.
        Thank you for your help.
        <strong> XXXX </strong>
            <br/> 
            <br />
        I want to remove all the HTML after the strong XXXX
            <br />
            <br />
        <strong> YYY </strong>
</p>
_HTML_

puts doc.at('//p/text()[1]').to_s.strip
# >> This is just an example, how to remove the next sentence using nokogiri in Ruby.
# >>         Thank you for your help.
```

---

Now if you want to remove unwanted,as per you,html content from the source html itself then you can probably try the below :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-_HTML_
<p>
        This is just an example, how to remove the next sentence using nokogiri in Ruby.
        Thank you for your help.
        <strong> XXXX </strong>
            <br/> 
            <br />
        I want to remove all the HTML after the strong XXXX
            <br />
            <br />
        <strong> YYY </strong>
</p>
_HTML_


doc.xpath('//p/* | //p/text()').count # => 10
ndst = doc.search('//p/* | //p/text()')[1..-1]
ndst.remove


puts doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body><p>
# >>         This is just an example, how to remove the next sentence using nokogiri in Ruby.
# >>         Thank you for your help.
# >>         </p></body></html>
```

Comment: Yes something like this, how does it works? why the result did not include the "strong" part?

Comment: @kilua I used the xpath function `text()`. so it picks up all the text nodes.don't need to care which text node packed with which element node. This is how `text()` works.As you were interested in the first text so need `[1]`,That's it.

Comment: The problem is, the content is not static, its always keep changing. But it still has the "strong" XXXX part, the HTML content (middle) part can become more than 1 paragraph. So the text()[n] cannot really solve the issue. is there any way I search search the XXXX part and remove it? Thanks

Comment: @kilua remove what part ? why ? then try `puts doc.at('//p/text()[1]').to_s.strip`